# Do you need to normalize sets before computing covariance?

Tags: statistics, random-variables

Suppose I am trying to compute the covariance between two sets X and Y.

If the values in X are all above 1000 and the values of Y are all below 1, do we need to normalize the sets before doing the covariance calculation, i.e. divide each element in X by its maximum element and the same for Y?

Comment: What do you mean by the "covariance between two sets"? Covariance is a measure of the joint variability of random variables. There is no reason to assume that arbitrary sets even have any sort of probability measure defined on them, for covariance to make sense in the first place.

Comment: If you have data set consisting of pairs of numbers (X,Y) and want to apply the usual formula for the sample covariance and the X and Y parts have widely different scales, then to reduce round-off errors you might very well want to first scale both the X and Y.  "Good" software does this behind the scenes when there is a "covariance" (or even "variance") function.  But first you need to clarify your question.

Comment: "Normalized covariance" is called correlation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the covariance directly without scaling.

Scaling will change the covariance, and your suggested method will not be particularly useful (subtracting each set's mean and then dividing by its standard deviation may be slightly more intuitive).  The only real justification would be to avoid rounding errors for extremely large or extremely small values.

If you do find the covariance of the scaled data sets using either method, you can multiply this, by both of the scaling factors you divided by earlier, to give the covariance of the original data sets.